# Knockout.js: disable other checkboxes when one checkbox is selected

Tags: jquery, checkbox, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I'm new with Knockout and I'm struggling with the following issue.

I have made some product divs that are clickable (with a hidden checkbox). If someone clicks on a div, a hidden checkbox is selected and the style changes.

Now I want to add dependencies, as some products cannot be ordered simultaneously. I want to do this based on the checkbox value (true/false). So let's say, if product 1 is selected, product 2 and 3 should be disabled with an additional class "disabledDiv". However, this event change binder does not do the trick for me. I doesn't even fire an alert.

```
self.valueCheckboxChanged = function() {
  alert('value has changed')
}
```

Can someone please help me, I'm at a loss. I made a simplified JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/Seabiscuito/f1qnr8a2/) to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 2):

*Fix 1:* Remove the `value` binding from the checkbox.

*Fix 2:* Add the `hidden` attribute to the checkbox to prevent any problems with event bubbling (a tap on the input would toggle the value, bubble to the div and toggle it back)

*Fix 3:* Subscribe to a checkbox' `isChecked` observable instead of using the `change` event. For instance:

```
self.checkedProducts = ko.pureComputed(function() {
  return this.products().filter(function(p) {
    return p.isChecked();
  });
}, this);

self.checkedProducts.subscribe(function(checked) {
  // Do something with the checked products
}, this);
```

The last part is the most complicated part. Make sure you don't end up in an infinite loop! <s>If you explain what kind of dependencies you want to create, I can edit this last section to better reflect your needs.</s>

Here's an example that shows the relation between the items through a `subscribe`:

```js
function Cart(products) {
  this.products = products.map(Product.fromData);
  
  const main = this.products[0];
  const others = this.products.slice(1);
    
  main.isChecked.subscribe((included) => {
    const action = included 
      ? Product.disable
      : Product.enable;
      
    others.forEach(action);
  });
};

function Product(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.isChecked = ko.observable(false);
  this.enabled = ko.observable(true);
};

Product.prototype.toggle = function() {
  if (!this.enabled()) return;
  this.isChecked(!this.isChecked());
};

Product.prototype.enable = function() {
  this.enabled(true);
};

Product.prototype.disable = function() {
  this.enabled(false);
  this.isChecked(false);
};

Product.enable = p => p.enable();
Product.disable = p => p.disable();
Product.fromData = name => new Product(name);


ko.applyBindings(new Cart(["Deluxe Lunch", "Drink", "Food"]));
```

```css
li { opacity: .5; list-style: none; padding: 1em; border-radius: 3px; border: 1px solid black; margin-bottom: .25em; }
.isChecked { background: yellow }
.isEnabled { opacity: 1; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="foreach: products">

  <li data-bind="click: toggle.bind($data), css: { isChecked: isChecked, isEnabled: enabled }">
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isChecked" hidden />
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
  </li>


</ul>
```

Comment: If someone selects Product 1, they cannot choose Product 2 and 3 anymore. Therefore, if someone selects Product 1, I want to disable the entire div of Product 2 and 3, so that those divs are no longer clickable and customers cannot select those products. I have done that previously by adding another class ('disabledDiv') to the extraProduct div.

Comment: I have updated my JSFiddle with Product 4 to illustrate what I'm trying to accomplish with Product 2 and 3: https://jsfiddle.net/Seabiscuito/f1qnr8a2/37/

Product 4 is now already disabled, but I would like it to addClass ('disabledDiv') when Product 1 is selected. Hope it is more clear now!

Comment: I added a quick example that shows how the different items' states can be linked. It's hard for me to see where you'd define the logic concerning the dependencies between products though.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm struggling with one last thing. My array consists of objects, with various product variables (name, price, duration etc). I cannot manage to switch the code from a simple array to a more complex array with objects. As soon as I switch to an array with objects, the name changes in [Object Object] 

For image: https://ibb.co/dWMEVx

Comment: I made an updated version of my JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Seabiscuito/f1qnr8a2/

In the end, price should be also a data-bind="text: price", but I cannot manage to do that..

Comment: Your product data is an array of objects, while my example made a `Product` instance based on just the name. You can change the constructor to take the object . See line 57 https://jsfiddle.net/5os8jopz/1/

Comment: Your a hero!! Thank you so much!!